# Azure Search Indexer with Azure SQL datasource using High watermark column produce inefficient query

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

I have an Azure SQL table which is synced to Azure Search using an indexer.
The indexer datasource is configured with a "change tracking policy" High watermark column.

Based on the link below, it is recommended to use a rowversion data type for the high water mark column.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-connecting-azure-sql-database-to-azure-search-using-indexers

So my SQL table have a RowVersion field of datatype timestamp, with an index defined on it.

When I look at the Query Performance Insight of my database, one of the worst performing query is the following:

```
(@hwm bigint)SELECT * FROM [dam].[Asset] WHERE [RowVersion] > @hwm ORDER BY [RowVersion]
```

I assume this is the query made by indexer, since the count of executions fits with the refresh frequency of the indexer.

Notice how this query is using a bigint parameter.
This cause a full index scan when I look at the query execution plan... look at the Predicate, it uses a CONVERT_IMPLICIT()
[image]

Why isn't the indexer using the correct timestamp datatype to prevent this casting ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for reporting this! We will look into casting issue.

However, I think you will be better off by using Integrated Change Tracking: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-connecting-azure-sql-database-to-azure-search-using-indexers#sql-integrated-change-tracking-policy

Can you use that instead?

Comment: Hmm, index is in production usage. What kind of impact is there when changing the Change Tracking Policy ?

Comment: Thinking out loud, our database is geo-replicated. We could use the replica database as the datasource for the indexer ? This would stop affecting our production database until you fix the casting issue.

Comment: Switching change detection policy requires resetting indexer's change detection state using Reset Indexer API. This will mean that everything in your table will be re-indexed.

Comment: Read-only replicas cannot be used when using rowversion columns for change tracking, because correct rowversion semantics internally rely on using MIN_ACTIVE_ROWVERSION SQL function, which is only supported on primary DB, not on RO replicas.

Comment: @Guillaume: Does that answer your question?

Comment: @JacobJedryszek - Is there any public tracking of this casting issue, is this something that has been since addressed?

Comment: Having used Integrated Change Tracking policy for a couple months, it generates huge change tracking backing tables and very high database usage. We would like to switch back to the rowversion watermark column. Is the casting issue fixed ?

Answer (score 0):

The docs for [creating an indexer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-connecting-azure-sql-database-to-azure-search-using-indexers#converthighwatermarktorowversion) were [updated](https://github.com/MicrosoftDocs/azure-docs/commit/29cc49367374129e176f10dbddb7767e259bc3ae) on 6/17/20 with a description of a configuration parameter used when creating the index: `convertHighWaterMarkToRowVersion`.

> If you're using a rowversion data type for the high water mark column, consider setting the convertHighWaterMarkToRowVersion property in indexer configuration. Setting this property to true results in the following behaviors:
>
> - Uses the rowversion data type for the high water mark column in the indexer SQL query. Using the correct data type improves indexer query performance.
> - Subtracts one from the rowversion value before the indexer query runs. Views with one-to-many joins may have rows with duplicate rowversion values. Subtracting one ensures the indexer query doesn't miss these rows.